# Bootstrap 4: .row causes horizontal overflow

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have created the fiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/qjpay7e3/3/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <label class="col-lg-4" >Gallery Plus</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I have two components  and checkbox in div. I want both elements on the same line for that I used **row** class of **Bootstrap 4**.

But I don't know why I m not getting those elements on the same line.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine. as you have used -lg therefore your label and checkbox is appearing on the same line for large screen.

Why it is not working for screen < large??

this is because styles in bootstrap are applied to up in hierarchy which means that if you had column -sm(smaller) applied than it would be applicable to screen in up hierarchy i.e to -md and -lg screen.

in your case u have applied it on -lg screen so it is only applicable to screen with size >= lg.

Comment: if you want it to appear on the same line than try this https://jsfiddle.net/qjpay7e3/14/ using <div class="col"> with both label n checkbox will divide them in equal spaces i.e. col-6 and col-6

Comment: so just add <label class="col-8" > and  <div class="col-4"> if this works for u please upvote and except it as your answer

Comment: do u want to hide them for sm and xs?

Comment: nope i want display it as it is because for xs and sm i wrote different custom CSS...

Comment: so you should apply it from -md

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qjpay7e3/14/ try resizing the ouput column of fiddle

Answer (score -2):

It's because of the column definitions, setting `col-lg-4` and `col-lg-8` automatically uses `col-12` and `col-12` meaning if your window is smaller than the `lg` minimum definition, they will drop a line to match the definition.

However, if you use `col-4` and `col-8`, they appear on the same row. They dont appear on the same row when using the `-lg` modifiers as you probably arent using a screen that's wide enough

Comment: I don't want that 4 and 8 structure for -xs and -sm so, I have to use that -lg in code..

Comment: there is a `-md` that you can use, which might be more appropriate

Comment: After some RD I found bootstrap applies " flex-wrap: wrap; " CSS on .row elements if i change it to " flex-wrap: nowrap; " it works.. So is it anything which we can change?

Comment: have you tried the `-md` column qualifier? if you say that `-lg` cant be used, then it will suit you

Comment: I can't use -md for my scenario I can use only -lg but I tried with -md but it is not working...

Comment: please see [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options) link, it explains the different qualifiers